# Using OpenAL to output sound to a specific channel to a 7.1

Tags: openal

all.
I have a project where I need to interface with a A/V receiver via an X-Fi sound blaster card. The A/V receiver is connected to a 7.1 speaker system. I would like to know the start to finish way to access each of the 7.1 channels individually so that I can direct aircraft cockpit information in a simulator. I am using OpenAL and am writing this code in C. I have developed some code that I thought should do the trick, but I am getting audio bleed through on the other 6 speakers. Below is a sample of some of the code I have already written. I hope that someone can help me here.

Thanks, Vincent.`{
    ALuint NorthWestSource;
    ALint  PlayStatus;

```
switch (event)
{
    case EVENT_COMMIT:
        //Load user selected .wav file into the buffer that is initialized here, "InitBuf".
        LoadDotWavFile();        

        //Generate a source, attach buffer to source, set source position, and play sound.
        alGenSources(NumOfSources, &NorthWestSource);      
        ErrorCheck();

        //Attach the buffer that contains the .wav file's data to the source. 
        alSourcei(NorthWestSource, AL_BUFFER, WavFileDataBuffer);
        ErrorCheck();

        //Set source's position, velocity, and orientation/direction.
        alSourcefv(NorthWestSource, AL_POSITION, SourcePosition);
        ErrorCheck();
        alSourcefv(NorthWestSource, AL_VELOCITY, SourceVelocity);
        ErrorCheck();
        alSourcefv(NorthWestSource, AL_DIRECTION, SourceDirectionNorthWest);
        ErrorCheck();
        alSourcei(NorthWestSource, AL_SOURCE_RELATIVE, AL_TRUE);
        ErrorCheck();
        alSourcei(NorthWestSource, AL_CONE_INNER_ANGLE, 180);
        ErrorCheck();
        alSourcei(NorthWestSource, AL_CONE_OUTER_ANGLE, 270);
        ErrorCheck();
        SetCtrlVal(panelHandle, PANEL_SOURCEISSET, 1);

        //Play the user selected file by playing the sources.
        alSourcePlay(NorthWestSource);
        ErrorCheck();

        //Check that the .wav file has finished playing and if so clean things up.
        do
        {
            alGetSourcei(NorthWestSource, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &PlayStatus);
            if(PlayStatus != AL_PLAYING)
            {
                printf("File done playing. \n");
            }//End do-while if statement
        }
        while(PlayStatus == AL_PLAYING);

        //Clean things up more before exiting out of this audio projection.
        alDeleteSources(NumOfSources, &NorthWestSource);
        ErrorCheck();
        alDeleteBuffers(NumOfBuffers, &WavFileDataBuffer);
        ErrorCheck();
        SetCtrlVal(panelHandle, PANEL_SOURCEISSET, 0);
        //alDeleteBuffers(NumOfBuffers, 
        break;
}
return 0;
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

I am confronted with the same problem. I want to play a tone to either the left or right ear. The only way I have found so far is to produce a stereo buffer (7.1 buffer for you) with the sound, then overwrite the information on the other channel (... other 7 channels for you) with zeros, and then play it back from a source in front of the listener.

This is my workaround. I know that it is clumsy. But I haven't found any better if you want to stay in openAL and to avoid programming using ALSA directly (for Linux) or CoreAudio (for Mac).

To answer your question more directly: No, there does not seem to be a direct way of saying (as I had wished for): "Speaker #3 say 'Hello World'! All other speakers remain silent."

Cheers,

farid